# Apply AutoCorrect on inserted text using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation, autocorrect

When I am inserting text into Word using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, the inserted text will not have auto correct applied to it.

I have for example an auto correct in Word which should change `auto correct` to `AUTO CORRECT`.

```cs
string text = "is this auto correct? Is this auto format 1/2?";
int start = word.Selection.Start;
word.Selection.TypeText(text);
int end = word.Selection.Start;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range insertedRange = word.ActiveDocument.Range(start, end);
insertedRange.AutoFormat();

// In Word the text will come over as:
// Actual:   "is this auto correct? is this auto format ½?"
// Expected: "Is this AUTO CORRECT? Is this auto format ½?"
//            ^       ^^^^ ^^^^^^^  ^
```

Auto format works, Word will change `1/2` to `½`. But Word will not change `auto correct` to `AUTO CORRECT`.

I cannot find an a function for applying auto correct for the text I have inserted. [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range?view=word-pia) does not appear to have such a function.

The closest I have come is to enumerate all the [auto corrections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.autocorrect?view=word-pia&viewFallbackFrom=excel-pia) myself and applying the auto correct if necessary [see here](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/getting-the-list-of-autocorrect-enties-in-word.3203945/).
But this approach does not include `Capitalize first letter of sentences` and other such auto correct features in Word.

If I manually place my caret next to the `auto correct` text and press `<space>` the text will change to `AUTO CORRECT`, I need a way to trigger this from code.

How can I apply auto correct to the text I have inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word's AutoCorrect functionality evaluates each keystroke as it is input to determine if what has come before needs correction. This is why typing a space or a grammar mark triggers a correction for the initial capital in a sentence or a custom AutoCorrect "Replace text as you type" rule. C# methods such as `Selection.TypeText` or `Range.InsertAfter` won't work because the individual keystrokes cannot be evaluated. However, `SendKeys.Send` sends individual keystrokes that can be evaluated by AutoCorrect. All that is needed is to break down the string and submit the individual characters:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Word.Application word = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

string text = "is this auto correct? Is this auto format 1/2?";
int start = word.Selection.Start;
//Loop through string characters and input with SendKeys to access AutoCorrect
foreach (char c in text)
{
    SendKeys.Send(c.ToString());
}
int end = word.Selection.Start;
Range insertedRange = word.ActiveDocument.Range(start, end);
insertedRange.AutoFormat();
```

There will be a slight delay in the inserting of the text due to `SendKeys` and the AutoCorrect being called for each character, however this should not be an issue for most applications.